# MongoDB 1.8: sort() is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I try this:

```
.find().sort({"day" => 1})
```

And it says `"wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)"`.

The documentation says it receives arguments.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the format you're seeing is for interacting with the MongoDB server directly, not for the Ruby driver. Have you tried using the `:sort` option of the actual `find` command?

```
.find({}, :sort => 'day')
```

Also, this may work:

```
.find({}).sort([["day", 1]])
```